# Load serialized data in multiple applications C#

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryfiles, binary-data

Scenario:
I have a program which uses a simple class to generate game data. Using the said program, I write the data out using serialization and BinaryFormatter to a file to be used by a second program. Reading the data from this initial program works without issue.

Problem:
It's probably down to my ignorance to how serialized files are handled, but I cannot then load this data into a second program, the actual game itself.

saveGame code (in program 1):

```
static List<GameData> gameData;
static GameData currentData;

private void saveGame(Sudoku sdk) {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = null;
    try {
        if(!File.Exists(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty])) {
            file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.CreateNew);
        } else {
            file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.Append);
        }
        currentData = setGameData(sdk);
        bf.Serialize(file, currentData);
        savePuzzleLog();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException("saveGame", e);
    }
    if(file != null) {
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

loadGameData: (in program 2)

```
public static List<GameData> gameData;

public bool loadGameData() {
    if(gameData == null) {
        gameData = new List<GameData>();
    } else {
        gameData.Clear();
    }
    bool loadData = true;
    bool OK = false;
    if(File.Exists(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty])) {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.Open);
        while(loadData) {
            try {
                GameData gd = new GameData();
                gd = (GameData)bf.Deserialize(file);
                gameData.Add(gd);
                OK = true;
                if(file.Position == file.Length) {
                    loadData = false;
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Debug.LogException(e);
                loadData = false;
                OK = false;
            }
        }
        if(file != null) {
            file.Close();
        }
    } else {
        Debug.LogWarning(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty] + " does not exist!");
    }
    return OK;
}
```

GameData Class: (1st program)

```
[Serializable]
class GameData {
    private int gameID;
    private List<int> contentArray;
    private int difficultyValue;

    public GameData(List<int> data = null) {
        id = -1;
        difficulty = -1;
        if(content != null) {
            content.Clear();
        } else {
            content = new List<int>();
        }
        if(data != null) {
            foreach(int i in data) {
                content.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public int id {
        get {
            return this.gameID;
        }
        set {
            this.gameID = value;
        }
    }

    public int difficulty {
        get {
            return this.difficultyValue;
        }
        set {
            this.difficultyValue = value;
        }
    }

    public List<int> content {
        get {
            return this.contentArray;
        }
        set {
            this.contentArray = value;
        }
    }
}
```

GameData Class: (2nd program) The only difference is declaring as public

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData {
    private int gameID;
    private List<int> contentArray;
    private int difficultyValue;

    public GameData(List<int> data = null) {
        id = -1;
        difficulty = -1;
        if(content != null) {
            content.Clear();
        } else {
            content = new List<int>();
        }
        if(data != null) {
            foreach(int i in data) {
                content.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public int id {
        get {
            return this.gameID;
        }
        set {
            this.gameID = value;
        }
    }

    public int difficulty {
        get {
            return this.difficultyValue;
        }
        set {
            this.difficultyValue = value;
        }
    }

    public List<int> content {
        get {
            return this.contentArray;
        }
        set {
            this.contentArray = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What my question is, is how do I save the data out in one program and be able to load it using a different program without getting serialization errors or do I need to use an alternate save/load method and/or class structure?

Comment: I did try to answer you, but i had to completely guess what your problem exaclty was, an error message (the exception you talked about) would help greatly

Comment: Use `BinaryFormatter` **only** if you are serializing/deserializing data in the same assembly. There are many other serializers, it's not clear why you must use this serialzer.

Comment: In a game, i would bet on the anti-cheat :), the text based serializers would produce a file that would be way too easy to modify

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained, the secondary app is written in Unity and the error I receive is:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sudoku Manager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

...where "Seduko Manager" is the name of program 1 that generates the data file.

@Sidewinder94 you are absolutely correct, this is for anti-cheat as you say, using a text based file it's too easy to find the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do it i made it this way :

An independant dll (assembly) containing the class holding the data (for you the GameData class), and utility methods to save/load from a file.

Your two other projects must then reference this dll (assembly) and you should be able to (de)serialize correctly.

What I think the issue is in your case is that the BinaryFormatter does not only save the data in the file, but also the complete Type of the serialized object.

When you try to deserialize in another similar object, even if the structure is the same, the full name of the class is not (because the assembly name is not).

Comment: Is there no way to add a hash code or anything that the program must know in order to read the data, rather than the assembly name / version. As I explained, it may be my misunderstanding of how serialization works that's causing the issue.  I know I can easily switch to a struct and resolve it, but from what I've read, structs are a thing of the past and classes should be used instead, or have I misunderstood that too?

Comment: nope ,no way to use a Hash, it's how the Binary Serialization works in .NET. As I said, you have to create a third project (a dll project) that will contain the GameData Class. You'll then have to reference this dll in both project (the manager and the game) to be able to (de)serialize properly

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've sorted it using the advice given.  Instead of using BinaryFormatter I have used BinaryWriter and BinaryReader as follows...

In program 1 (the creator):

```
    private byte[] setByteData(Sudoku sdk) {
        List<int> clues = sdk.puzzleListData();
        byte[] bd = new byte[puzzleSize];
        SudokuSolver solver = new SudokuSolver();
        List<int> solution = solver.Solve(sdk.Copy(), false, currentDifficulty).puzzleListData();
        for(int i = 0; i < puzzleSize; i++) {
            bd[i] = Convert.ToByte(solution[i] + (clues[i] == 0 ? 0xF0 : 0));
        }
        return bd;
    }

    private GameData setGameData(Sudoku sdk) {
        List<int> clues = sdk.puzzleListData();
        GameData gd = new GameData();
        gd.id = puzzleList.Items.Count;
        gd.difficulty = currentDifficulty;
        SudokuSolver solver = new SudokuSolver();
        List<int> solution = solver.Solve(sdk.Copy(), false, currentDifficulty).puzzleListData();
        for(int i = 0; i < puzzleSize; i++) {
            gd.content.Add(solution[i] + (clues[i] == 0 ? 0xF0 : 0));
        }
        return gd;
    }

    private List<int> getByteData(byte[] data) {
        List<int> retVal = new List<int>();
        foreach(byte i in data) {
            if(i > 9) {
                retVal.Add(i - 0xF0);
            } else {
                retVal.Add(0);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private string getGameData(List<int> data) {
        string retVal = "";
        foreach(int i in data) {
            if(i > 9) {
                retVal += (i - 0xF0).ToString();
            } else {
                retVal += i.ToString();
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    private void saveGame(Sudoku sdk) {
        FileStream file = null;
        BinaryWriter bw = null;
        try {
            if(!File.Exists(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty])) {
                file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.CreateNew);
            } else {
                file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.Append);
            }
            bw = new BinaryWriter(file);
            currentData = setGameData(sdk);
            byte[] bd = setByteData(sdk);
            bw.Write(currentData.id);
            bw.Write(currentData.difficulty);
            bw.Write(bd);
            savePuzzleLog();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Debug.LogException("saveGame", e);
        }
        if(file != null) {
            if(bw != null) {
                bw.Flush();
                bw.Close();
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

In program 2: (the actual game)

```
    public bool loadGameData() {
        if(gameData == null) {
            gameData = new List<GameData>();
        } else {
            gameData.Clear();
        }
        bool loadData = true;
        bool OK = false;
        if(File.Exists(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty])) {
            FileStream file = File.Open(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty], FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file);
            while(loadData) {
                try {
                    GameData gd = new GameData();
                    gd.id = br.ReadInt32();
                    gd.difficulty = br.ReadInt32();
                    gd.content = getByteData(br.ReadBytes(puzzleSize));
                    gameData.Add(gd);
                    OK = true;
                    if(file.Position == file.Length) {
                        loadData = false;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Debug.LogException(e);
                    loadData = false;
                    OK = false;
                }
            }
            if(file != null) {
                file.Close();
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogWarning(gameDataFile[currentDifficulty] + " does not exist!");
        }
        return OK;
    }
```

The class structure is the same as before but using this method has resolved my issue and I can now create the data files using my creator and load the data comfortably using the actual game.

Thanks all for your assistance and advice to help me get this sorted.